# How to migrate a project from npm to pnpm

Tags: node.js, npm, pnpm

We have built a project with a deep tree of dependencies with `npm install` and have a lot of issues under Microsoft Windows (secondary target).

I have read about `pnpm` and it seems to be a solution for us.

How to migrate our nested repository?

Build a new one from scratch, using `pnpm`?

Comment: Do you mean you rely on a npm-shrinkwrap.json or package-lock.json because the project is fragile and would break with a different set of packages? you may create pnpm lockfile from npm lockfile by running "pnpm import"

Comment: if you have a monorepo with many packages, you need to configure a pnpm workspace. You basically need a  pnpm-workspace.yaml file + some configs in a .npmrc in the root of the repo. You can read about it here: https://pnpm.js.org/docs/en/pnpm-recursive.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I have made a backup of `node_modules` and rebuilt it from scratch with `pnpm` and added `concat` to have only one JavaScript source and applied `Google-compiler` to it.

The only difficulty was about `bootstrap` because it has changed a lot in two years. We need to keep the old look of it, so the command I used is `pnpm install bootstrap@3.3.7`.

After completion, the look and feel was identical but `node_modules` has grew from 8 MB to 12 MB...

Comment: So no improvement of pnpm over npm if file size grew? What is the size unity Mo?

Comment: Sorry, I'm French : mega octet is megabyte, MB (correction done in the text).

Comment: It should be a good solution for multiple projects sharing dependencies. It seems that initial size is bigger but overall savings can improve over time.

Comment: You have to consider that there is a "bug" in the windows explorer and folder sizes might be wrong when hard links are used but pnpm makes use of hard links. So...

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28077454/windows-hard-links-disk-usage-inconsistency)

Answer (score 4):

You can `pnpm import` which takes your `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock` and generates pnpm's lock file `pnpm-lock.yaml`. After that, you can `pnpm install` to install the dependencies of the project.

[documentation](https://pnpm.io/cli/import)